# iOS table view: How to fix 1st row but allow re-ordering of all other rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table view, I want to fix the 1st row but allow re-ordering of all other rows. I thus used

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.row > 0; // row 0 cannot be moved
}
```

so that all rows except the 1st one show the re-order control during editing.
The problem is that, although I cannot move now the 1st row directly, it is still possible to move any other row to the top of the table, so that the 1st row moves to the 2nd place, which makes `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` useless in this case.
I had expected to be able to use a delegate method that allows me to specify if a row can be moved **to a certain place**, but such a method seems not to exist.
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing the delegate method `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`

From the docs:

```
Asks the delegate to return a new index path to retarget a proposed move of a row.
```

So it seems what you want is to do is if toProposedIndexPath is your first row then you would want to return the second row instead.

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right. I just forgot to look up the table view delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[UITableViewDelegate tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:]`. If the proposed IndesPath is the one you do not want to move then return proper index path from this method. This will handle visual move of row as you want.

You also need to update data structure in `[UITableViewDataSource tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:]`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be to make first cell as header of tableView.
If header already exists then you can use custom header view with Header+FirstRow content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this method, may be it will work for you. :)

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

In this method, if you don't update your data source if `proposedDestinationIndexPath` is the first row.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one section in tableview use this

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

    targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath

    toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {

if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0) {

    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection: proposedDestinationIndexPath.section];

}

// Allow the proposed destination.

return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
```

}